# Mass install apps using FTP/HTTP

Tags: installation, adb, file-transfer

I would like to mass install few apps at one time from a single FTP server - from Android phone, without using adb command.

The phone will be rooted and will have and the option to install non-Market apps turned on.

I know it is possible to install many apps using single adb command (http://www.androidsim.net/2011/06/how-to-18-mass-installing-multiple.html) but I would like to do this **using an Android app** that would download all the apps and install them.
I am looking for a ready-made solution (app/code snippet) or a clues for implementing FTP connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way of [programatically installing APKs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically/4969421#4969421)

the code snippet you're looking for is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've searched Android SE archives but didn't search SO archives.